# Syntax error in PHP MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query but get a syntax error:

> Unknown column 'k.Fund_Name' in 'field list'

Dreamweaver reflects no syntax errors.  Only in the browser.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("
select 
      k.Fund_Name Title,
      k.Fund_Yield_9 Year_9,
      k.Fund_Yield_8 Year_8,
      k.Fund_Yield_7 Year_7,
      k.Fund_Yield_6 Year_6,
      k.Fund_Yield_5 Year_5,
      k.Fund_Yield_4 Year_4,
      k.Fund_Yield_3 Year_3,
      k.Fund_Yield_2 Year_2,
      k.Fund_Yield_1 Year_1,
      k.Fund_Yield_0 Year_0

from
( select    
      a.Fund_Name Fund_Name,
      j.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_9,
      i.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_8,
      h.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_7,
      g.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_6,
      f.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_5,
      e.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_4,
      d.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_3,
      c.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_2,
      b.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_1,
      a.Fund_Yield Fund_Yield_0

from
            ( select  A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_Minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 0 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) a


Left Outer Join ( select
              A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 1 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) b on ( a.ID_CARTERA = b.ID_CARTERA )


Left Outer Join ( select
              A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 2 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) c on ( a.ID_CARTERA = c.ID_CARTERA )


Left Outer Join ( select    
              A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1                            
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 3 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) d on ( a.ID_CARTERA = d.ID_CARTERA )


Left Outer Join ( select    
              A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 4 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) e on ( a.ID_CARTERA = e.ID_CARTERA )


Left Outer Join ( select    
              A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1                            
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 5 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) f on ( a.ID_CARTERA = f.ID_CARTERA )


Left Outer Join ( select    
              A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 6 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) g on ( a.ID_CARTERA = g.ID_CARTERA )


Left Outer Join ( select    
              A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 7 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) h on ( a.ID_CARTERA = h.ID_CARTERA )


Left Outer Join ( select    
              A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 8 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) i on ( a.ID_CARTERA = i.ID_CARTERA )

Left Outer Join ( select
              A.ID_Cartera,
              A.F_ANO Year,
              H.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Fund_Yield,
              C.DES_CARTERA_CC Fund_Benchmark_Name,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTBENCH, 2) Fund_Benchmark_Yield,
              D.DES_CARTERACLASE Class_Name,
              ROUND(G.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Class_Yield,
              E.DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP Special_Class_Name,
              ROUND(F.POR_RENTABILIDAD, 2) Special_Class_Yield,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSBENCH, 2) Plus_minus_Benchmark,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASE, 2) Plus_Minus_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_RENTMENOSCLASEESP, 2) Plus_Minus_Special_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASE, 2) Percentile_Class,
              ROUND(A.POR_PERCENTILCLASEESP, 2) Percentile_Special_Class
    from      dr_rent_carteras_anos A
              Join det_refcru_carterasbench B on ( A.ID_CARTERA = B.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras C on ( B.ID_CARTERABENCH = C.ID_CARTERA )
              Join mcarteras_clases D on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE = D.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras_clasesesp E on ( A.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clasesesp_anos F on ( A.F_ANO = F.F_ANO and E.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP = F.ID_CARTERACLASE_ESP )
              Join dr_rent_clases_anos G on ( A.F_ANO = G.F_ANO and D.ID_CARTERACLASE = G.ID_CARTERACLASE )
              Join mcarteras H on ( A.ID_CARTERA = H.ID_CARTERA )
    where     A.ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA
    And       A.IND_RENTABILIDAD = 1
    And       A.F_ANO = ( select  MAX(F_ANO ) - 9 from  dr_rent_carteras_anos  where ID_CARTERA = $ID_CARTERA ) ) j on ( a.ID_CARTERA = j.ID_CARTERA ) ) K

")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I see no aliased table `k`, only `K` (capitalized)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have aliased your last subselect with a capital K, but in the fields you select you have small k's

Comment: @johnhalbert by the way. Are you out of your mind? That must be the worst SQL query I have ever seen.